# Preserve subdirectories in webpack 5

Tags: webpack, subdirectory, webpack-5

I had a question and I did not find anything (for WebPack 5)
I created a folder called `svg` inside of my `images` folder, but when webpack compiles it into the `dist` folder, all of the images get flattened into that one images folder.
Is there something to be able preserve subdirectories? (in webpack 5)

```js
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/i,
    type: "asset/resource",
    generator: {
        filename: "images/[name][ext]",
    },
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to pass filename as a function, it may work (I'm not sure)

Comment: @felixmosh I did, but I still haven't achieved anything 

Comment: Does, it get called? what arguments it gets?

Comment: @felixmosh I found the solution with your help. Thanks 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution,
The `filename` property can be a function, and with this property we can get the full path, which with a few changes can preserve subdirectories.

```js
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/i,
    type: "asset/resource",
    generator: {
        filename: (name) => {
            /**
             * @description Remove first & last item from ${path} array.
             * @example
             *      Orginal Path: 'src/images/avatar/image.jpg'
             *      Changed To: 'images/avatar'
             */
            const path = name.filename.split("/").slice(1, -1).join("/");
            return `${path}/[name][ext]`;
        },
    },
}
```

Thanks to [@felixmosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6539317/felixmosh)